# Reading RESX Content from the loaded DLL and NOT the RESX file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, localization, resx

I need to be really clear on this. I am not trying to read the myfile.resx file. I am trying to read the content from the myresourcenamespace.myfile.dll.

My hopes is to create a dictionary of my KVPs contained within the RESX content, by accessing that which is preloaded into the DLLs. My current solution depends too much on the files exisiting and a bunch of copying to insure that files are where they need to be. The DLLs are more reliable at this point.

I have been able to gain access to the assembly via "new resourcemanager(myassemblytype)", but I am stuck at this point. I cannot seem to read the actual content from memory. I continually run up against MissingManifestException when I try and access the content as a stream from the resource manager.

Here is my successful code:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("ViewRes.StaticMessages", true);
var myResManager = new ResourceManager("StaticMessages", 
                           System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(myType));
```

Here is my failure code:

```
using (var fileReader = new ResXResourceSet(
                           myResManager.GetStream(myResManager.BaseName)))
{
//.... code read here
}
```

The ResXResourceSet throws the MissingManifestException. I have tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("ViewRes.StaticMessages", true);
var myResManager = new ResourceManager("StaticMessages", 
                       System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(myType));
```

Try like this:

```
var myType = Type.GetType("ViewRes.StaticMessages", true);
var myResManager = new ResourceManager("StaticMessages", myType.Assembly);
// you could specify the desired culture for which you would like to get the
// resource values
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; 
var resourceSet = myResManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);
```

now you can loop:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in resourceSet)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: This looked promising. Though once applied, I am still encountering the same "MissingManifestResourceException".

Comment: GetResourceSet, GetObject, GetStream all generate this exception for me